# How to tokenize and tag those tokenized strings from my own custom dictionary using python nltk?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, nltk

I am new to python. I have to build a chatbot using python nltk -- my use case and expected output is this:

I have a custom dictionary of some categories (shampoo,hair,lipstick,face wash),
some brands (lakme,l'oreal,matrix), some entities ((hair concern: dandruff, hair falling out), (hair type: oily hair, dry hair), (skin type: fair skin, dark skin, dusky skin), etc.).

> I want to buy shampoo for hair falling out and dry hair

or

> Show me best lipsticks for fair skin and office wear

How do I extract values by category: shampoo, hair concern: hair falling out, hair type: dry hair

I am using python nltk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope  this is what you are looking for   `https://github.com/sujitpal/nltk-examples/tree/master/src/cener`